# Optimizing a huge VBO drawing on Android/iOS devices

Tags: android, c++, optimization, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

What I need to do is to render a relatively huge isometric map on a mobile device (OpenGL ES2.0, Android 4.2). I'm using 1 VBO for the terrain, 1 VBO for the shadow layer, and 1 VBO for the objects layer.
The performance is the issue, even with the very first VBO.

Here we go, I have the data type for filling the VBO:

```
typedef struct _ovlndVertex
{
    GLshort x;
    GLshort y;
} ovlndVertex;

typedef struct _ovlndTexture {
    GLfloat u;
    GLfloat v;
} ovlndTexture;


typedef struct _TexturedVertex
{
    ovlndVertex        vertices;
    ovlndTexture       texCoords;
    GLshort textureId;
} TexturedVertex;
```

Let's say we are rendering a 256x256 sized map, 4 vertices per tile, this gives us 256x256x4 = 262144 vertices in the VBO. Given the sizeof(TexturedVertex) == 16, this is 4194304 bytes of raw VBO data (around 4MB).

The main rendering job is done in the shaders. Here is their code:

The vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;                            
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;                            
//attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_textureId;                              

uniform        mat4 u_MVPMatrix;                        

#ifdef GL_ES                                        
//varying lowp vec4 v_fragmentColor;                    
varying lowp vec2 v_texCoord;
#else                                                
//varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;                        
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
#endif                                                

varying float v_textureId;

void main()                                            
{                                                    
    gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_position;            
//  v_fragmentColor = a_color;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;                        
    v_textureId = a_textureId.x;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES                                
precision lowp float;
precision lowp int;
precision lowp sampler2D;
#endif                                        

//varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;                
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
//uniform sampler2D u_texture0, u_texture1, u_texture2;
uniform sampler2D u_textures[16];
varying float v_textureId;
uniform int u_idxOffset;

void main()                                    
{                                  
    // strange enough, but binary search below works WAY faster than
    // plain texture array referencing by index like:
//    int idx = int(v_textureId) - u_idxOffset;
//    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[idx], v_texCoord);

    int index = int(v_textureId) - u_idxOffset;
    if(index < 8) //0-7
    {
        if(index < 4) // 0-4
        {
            if(index < 2) //0-1
            {
                if(index < 1)
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[0], v_texCoord);
                }
                else
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[1], v_texCoord);
                }
            } else // 2-3
            {
                if(index < 3)
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[2], v_texCoord);
                }
                else
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[3], v_texCoord);
                }
            }
        } else //4-7
        {
            if(index < 6) //4-5
            {
                if(index < 5)
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[4], v_texCoord);
                }
                else
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[5], v_texCoord);
                }
            } else // 6-7
            {
                if(index < 7)
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[6], v_texCoord);
                }
                else
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[7], v_texCoord);
                }
            }
        }
    } else //8-15
    {
        if(index < 12) //8-11
        {
            if(index < 10) //8-9
            {
                if(index < 9)
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[8], v_texCoord);
                }
                else
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[9], v_texCoord);
                }
            } else // 10-11
            {
                if(index < 11)
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[10], v_texCoord);
                }
                else
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[11], v_texCoord);
                }
            }
        } else //12-15
        {
            if(index < 14) //12-13
            {
                if(index < 13)
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[12], v_texCoord);
                }
                else
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[13], v_texCoord);
                }
            } else // 14-15
            {
                if(index < 15)
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[14], v_texCoord);
                }
                else
                {
                    gl_FragColor = /*v_fragmentColor * */texture2D(u_textures[15], v_texCoord);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, I'm aware of OpenGL ES culling of the vertices outside the viewport, and it works perfectly. On a high zoom level it renders smoothly showing 60FPS on the device, however, if I zoom out to view all the map (this is the primary point) the FPS drops to 20-30 even without object rendering and to 4-5 with object rendering (2 additional similar VBOs).

Here is the ADT's OpenGL ES Tracer output for a typical slow-to-render frame:
(Wall Clock time: 0.49ms, Thread Time 0.37ms)

```
glClear(mask = 16640)
glUseProgram(program = 22)
glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 2)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE1)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE2)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE3)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE4)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE5)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE6)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE7)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE8)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE9)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE10)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE11)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE12)
glUniform1i(location = 1, x = 0)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 123)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_SHORT, normalized = false, stride = 16, ptr = 0x0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 1)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 2)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 3)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 16, ptr = 0x0)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 16, ptr = 0x4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 3, size = 1, type = GL_SHORT, normalized = false, stride = 16, ptr = 0xc)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 124)
glDrawElements(mode = GL_TRIANGLES, count = 469374, type = GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices = 0x0)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 0)
glBindBuffer(target = GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer = 0)
glActiveTexture(texture = GL_TEXTURE0)
glUseProgram(program = 7)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(index = 2)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 0, ptr = 0x775470c0)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 0, ptr = 0x775470e0)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 8, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 16, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glBlendFunc(sfactor = GL_SRC_ALPHA, dfactor = GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUseProgram(program = 1)
glBlendFunc(sfactor = GL_LINES, dfactor = GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 2)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77530800)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77530810)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x7753080c)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x775295f8)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529608)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529604)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529878)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529888)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529884)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
eglSwapBuffers
```

FYI, here is the typical fast-rendering GUI frame (main menu actually, that gives me 60FPS):
(Wall Clock time: 1.10MS, Thread Time 0.70MS)

```
glClear(mask = 16640)
glUseProgram(program = 7)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(index = 2)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 0, ptr = 0x77538880)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 0, ptr = 0x775388a0)
glBlendFunc(sfactor = GL_SRC_ALPHA, dfactor = GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 8, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 16, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUseProgram(program = 1)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, 0.093229175, -0.17300725, 0.0, 1.0])
glBlendFunc(sfactor = GL_LINES, dfactor = GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 1)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 2)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77546f08)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77546f18)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77546f14)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, -0.23489577, -0.17300725, 0.0, 1.0])
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77538cb0)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77538cc0)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77538cbc)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, -0.20677078, -0.17300725, 0.0, 1.0])
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77538f00)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77538f10)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77538f0c)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, -0.15572912, -0.17300725, 0.0, 1.0])
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77539150)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77539160)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x7753915c)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, -0.1057291, -0.17300725, 0.0, 1.0])
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x775393a0)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x775393b0)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x775393ac)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, -0.0567708, -0.17300725, 0.0, 1.0])
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77537bc0)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77537bd0)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77537bcc)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, -0.020312428, -0.17300725, 0.0, 1.0])
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77537e10)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77537e20)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77537e1c)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, 0.02239585, -0.17300725, 0.0, 1.0])
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77538060)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77538070)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x7753806c)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUseProgram(program = 7)
glDisableVertexAttribArray(index = 2)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 0, ptr = 0x77533090)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 8, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 16, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 0, ptr = 0x775330b0)
glBlendFunc(sfactor = GL_SRC_ALPHA, dfactor = GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glUseProgram(program = 1)
glUniformMatrix4fv(location = 0, count = 1, transpose = false, value = [0.0010416667, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0018115942, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -9.765625E-4, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
glBlendFunc(sfactor = GL_LINES, dfactor = GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glBindTexture(target = GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture = 0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(index = 2)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77530800)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77530810)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x7753080c)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x775295f8)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529608)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529604)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529878)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529888)
glVertexAttribPointer(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x77529884)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 0, size = 3, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 1, size = 4, type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalized = true, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glVertexAttribPointerData(indx = 2, size = 2, type = GL_FLOAT, normalized = false, stride = 24, ptr = 0x??, minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 4)
glDrawArrays(mode = GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, first = 0, count = 4)
eglSwapBuffers
```

This renders OpenGL Tracers useless for me, because a faster-rendering frame shows more time (both Wall clock & Thread) than the slow one. Does this mean the problem is hidden somewhere in shaders? How do I profile them?

What I tried so far:

- changed all the GLuint to GLshort to minimize buffer size (gave me 28 to 16 bytes optimization of a vertex struct sizeof)
- played with GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW/GL_STATIC_DRAW method of sending the data to VBO (no difference to me)
- tried using lowp wherever I can
- tried single-textured rendering (no difference, this make me think the shaders are doing well)
- reduced the OpenGL calls to an absolute minimum (you can see the OGL call log above)
- removed all glGet* functions that could break the pipeline rendering

Any advice I could optimize this ?

Comment: There is no way you can "mip map" (downsample) when you zoom out?  Ie, create half-scale versions (repeatedly) down to 1x1.  Render from the bottom to the top until you run out of time, and then stop.  This increases the total amount of VBOs rendered by 1/3 if you have enough time (1+1/4+1/4*1/4+1/4*1/4*1/4+... = 1+1/3), and gives you fast frame otherwise.... might give some popping, dunno.

Comment: What is the tecnhique to magically choose the mipmap when zooming out from the point of view of the fragment shader? OpenGL ES doesn't support textureLod() function.

Comment: I think you need to optimize your fragment shader. You have tons of branches in it and branching in shaders can be really bad for performance.

Comment: I completely agree with Niklas. SIMD operations do not handle divergence well as separate parallel tasks within the same warp cannot execute different statements at the same time. To circumvent this, each instance within a warp will execute EVERY branch of your fragment shader (regardless of outcome) and will select the correct branch result after the fact. The only way I see the binary search approach being faster is due to some compiler optimization that removes your branch statements and replaces them with a cheap arithmetic operation that is somehow faster than your previous approach.

Answer (score 0):

You already did a good job. There is probably no more room for more micro optimisations.

Because there is a very little number of drawcalls, using VAO/VertexArrays to remove glVertexAttribPointer from the rendering loop should not help much.

> 4 vertices per tile

Why are you using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and glDrawArrays ? glDrawElements with indices will give you more flexibility (see after...).

> 20-30 even without object rendering and to 4-5 with object rendering (2 additional similar VBOs).

okay. so you end up with about 800k vertices. right ?
I have faced similar problems last year (1000k vertices). I finally choose to send more drawcalls instead of using complex shaders. Yes, binding a lot of data (16 textures binding !) slow down everything on this type of device.

> if I zoom out to view all the map (this is the primary point) the FPS drops

On an iPad 2, 1000k vertices on screen (with a lot more data per vertex than you) should render faster: more than 20 fps.

It appears than most of your data are static. **You could try to build a vbo or a list of indices per texture** (i don't kown which is faster), **simplify your fragment shader a lot.**

- bind a vbo with all "static data" (vertex positions, texture coordinates)
- for each texture

  1. bind the texture
  2. use glDrawElements with 'texture specific' list of indices.

You can store indices in a buffer: glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)
Or you can pass indices directly to glBindBuffer if they are dynamic. It's probably faster than you think.

Last detail: lowp everywhere is dangerous. try mediump.

Good luck, you are touching the device limits !

Comment: I need the complex fragment shader to mix the z-order of objects from different textures (buildings, trees, etc). That's why I can't simply replace this with several VBO's (one per texture) as you suggest. The ultimate choice of the texture for the object is done in the fragment shader. However, thanks for your reply, I will try iPad 3 today and its OpengGL ES profiler, since I can't find any suitable tool for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Since the fast frame shows a higher time for the graphics trace, it's likely that something else is causing the slowdown. You should profile the CPU and see what your main and render threads are doing. Hopefully it will show the bottleneck.

It would be useful to profile the CPU when you render a zoomed in view versus a zoomed out one, and see if anything stands out as a major difference between the two.

Comment: I did. The problem is the fill rate, as I said, CPU is almost idle. The Renderer Utilization is 99%-100% all the time when zoomed out.